error: failed to run custom build command for `etcd-client v0.11.1`
Getting error on a fresh build of agave.
$cargo build
error: failed to run custom build command for `etcd-client v0.11.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/sol/src/agave/target/debug/build/etcd-client-fa92d1b04cd272d3/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/auth.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/kv.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/rpc.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/v3election.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/v3lock.proto
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /home/sol/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/prost-build-0.11.9/src/lib.rs:1457:10:
  Could not find `protoc` installation and this build crate cannot proceed without
      this knowledge. If `protoc` is installed and this crate had trouble finding
      it, you can set the `PROTOC` environment variable with the specific path to your
      installed `protoc` binary.If you're on debian, try `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` or download it from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases
 For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc

  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: gen-syscall-list@2.1.0: (not a warning) Generating ../../../sdk/sbf/syscalls.txt from ../src/syscalls/mod.rs

error: failed to run custom build command for `solana-svm-conformance v2.1.0 (/home/sol/src/agave/svm-conformance)`


So installing protobuf fixed the issue.
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler
Maybe the README documentation should mention it.
